# Macbook Pro camera still not working (green light on) - tried heaps of suggested solutions to no avail

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, camera

My macbook pro camera does not work in facetime, photobooth, zoom, etc despite the green light being on.

What I've tried so far to solve it which hasn't worked:

- sudo killall VDCAssistant & AppleCameraAssistant command (returned "no matching processes were found")
- Rebooted macbook in safe mode (opened Facetime and it said "No Camera
  Available")
- Repaired disk using Disk Utility
- Reset the SMC

I have a feeling that it is a hardware failure. When I leave my laptop 1/3 the way open and tap the screen, the camera starts working properly (sometimes). However, when I then fully open it, the image freezes and returns back to a black screen.

My camera was working fine in January, however in February I updated from High Sierra to Mojave. But it was only until March I realised my camera no longer worked. Last week I updated from Mojave to Catalina, camera still doesn't work. I don't think updating my macbook was the reason but I just added this incase..

Is there anything to try short of hardware repair?

Comment: Sounds like a loose connection.

Answer (score 1):

No, you have exhausted the typical steps and if you can send it in for repair or feel you won’t break it worse by opening it yourself, a repair is in order.

Before a repair, make a backup of everything and wipe and reinstall the OS. You need that to start the repair and if it fixes things, you’ll save the cost and time of the repair.