# Macbook Pro camera not working green light flickering

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, camera

I am the culprit, I heard my camera could be accessible to hackers, so used code in the Terminal to turn the camera off. I never needed the camera until today!

I've tried:

sudo killall VDCAssistant & AppleCameraAssistant command, returned - no matching processes were found
Reset the SMC
Rebooted macbook in safe mode
Repaired disk using Disk Utility

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/387900/237687